# Android 6.0 not authorized to update wireless network when app is reinstalled

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

In Android 6.0 (Marshmallow) it is impossible to delete or modify wifi networks that are not created by the app itself.

But when the app creates wifi networks and later on is deleted, these networks remain. When the app is installed again and tries to create or modify these networks, the app is not authorised to do so.

Does anyone has seen this problem and knows a solution? Could it be that this is a bug?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Facing same issue. Please help.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this issue? if so please post an answer